# CartoDB, Choropleth and bucket numbers in skewed data sets

Tags: carto, choropleth

How can I maximise the number of buckets in the choropleth map?

We have a data set range from 1-14 and 7 is the most # of buckets available in the wizard.

Unfortunately, most of the data occurs between 1-5, with fewer values at the 6-14 end of the spectrum.

Our preference would be for 14 buckets. Unless I'm missing another obvious solution?

Comment: Have there been any solutions that don't involve hand coding css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many buckets as you need by adding them in the CartoCSS tab.

If you browse through the right toolbar of the Editor, one of the tabs is the CartoCSS one.

With a choropleth map of 7 buckets assigned, you'll have a code similar to this one:

```
/** choropleth visualization */

#geonames_stats{
  polygon-fill: #FFFFB2;
  polygon-opacity: 0.8;
  line-color: #FFF;
  line-width: 0.5;
  line-opacity: 1;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 1330044000] {
   polygon-fill: #B10026;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 33679000] {
   polygon-fill: #E31A1C;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 11651858] {
   polygon-fill: #FC4E2A;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 6064515] {
   polygon-fill: #FD8D3C;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 2789132] {
   polygon-fill: #FEB24C;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 395650] {
   polygon-fill: #FED976;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 51134] {
   polygon-fill: #FFFFB2;
}
```

You just need to add extra code in order to build your other buckets, just concatenating this pieces:

```
#geonames_stats [ population <= 51134] {
   polygon-fill: #FFFFB2;
}
```

Which, in general, are.

```
#your_table_name [constraint here] {
   styles here
}
```

This would give you a result like:

```
/** choropleth visualization */

#geonames_stats{
  polygon-fill: #FFFFB2;
  polygon-opacity: 0.8;
  line-color: #FFF;
  line-width: 0.5;
  line-opacity: 1;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 1330044000] {
   polygon-fill: #B10026;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 33679000] {
   polygon-fill: #E31A1C;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 11651858] {
   polygon-fill: #FC4E2A;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 6064515] {
   polygon-fill: #FD8D3C;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 2789132] {
   polygon-fill: #FEB24C;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 395650] {
   polygon-fill: #FED976;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 51134] {
   polygon-fill: #FFFFB2;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 40134] {
   polygon-fill: #055D00;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 30134] {
   polygon-fill: #2E5387;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 20134] {
   polygon-fill: #229A00;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 10134] {
   polygon-fill: #6B0FB2;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 9134] {
   polygon-fill: #A53ED5;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 4134] {
   polygon-fill: #136400;
}
#geonames_stats [ population <= 1134] {
   polygon-fill: #2E5387;
}
```

In order to build the color scales, I use this site: http://colorbrewer2.org/ Just find the color and copy the hexadecimal values to the CartoCSS :)

Also, you'd need to update the legends of your map in case you're using them. You can do this by going to the "Legends" tab in the toolbar.

In the bottom of the current colors, you will find a '+' symbol. Click there to add more buckets and assign the corresponding color to them (by default a grey one appears, as in the following image). You may also want to update the left and right labels, whose options are also available in this wizard.

[image: legends]

Hope this helps!